# Why getText() doesn't work to format a double value in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, number-formatting

The code given below doesn't work for me to format a double value coming from a DTO via struts `Action` class:

```
<s:textfield key="xyz.value" value="%{getText('format.number',{xyz.value})}" theme = "simple"/>
```

I've gone through [this](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html) link .
But this code is not working for me.
I've not done any changes in my action class for this. In propety file I've assigned value for `format.number` only. i.e `format.number = {0,number,#0.0##}`

Answer (score 1):

Your action should extend `ActionSupport` without it `getText` is not available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. getText() is available in my Action class. Do I need to do anything apart from which I've wrote in the question?

Comment: That's all you needed.